# Streaming Audio only from a link

Tags: objective-c, xcode, audio

I have went through many youtube tutorials and looked everywhere. I want to create a live streaming app, I want to click the button play and it plays the streaming audio, and when i click the Stop button it stops. here is my code. Although on my device no sound actually plays. I don't know what Im doing wrong.

I have imported `#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>` in both .m and .h

```
    -(IBAction)LiveStream3:(id)sender { 

  NSString *stream = @"http://audio2.radioreference.com/il_chicago_police2.mp3";

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: stream];



myAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url fileTypeHint:stream error:nil];
myAudio.numberOfLoops = 0;
[myAudio play];
[streamTitle setText:@"Chicago"];

        NSLog(@"Playing");
}

-(IBAction)stopAudio:(id)sender {
    [myAudio stop];
    [streamTitle setText:@""];
    NSLog(@"Stop");

}
```

Comment: what about using the `error` parameter?

Comment: Instead of `error:nil`.